# What are the limitations while using XGboost algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, data-science-model, boosting

Will XGBoost pose any problem while dealing with categorical variables with more than 2 levels.
For example, occupation variable can have values like doctor, engineer, lawyer, data scientist, farmer e.t.c.
If so what would be a better method to use in that case?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be more specific about what you mean by "fail". As an example, a practitioner could consider an `xgboost` model as a failure if it achieves < 80% accuracy.

Nevertheless, there are some annoying quirks in `xgboost` which similar packages don't suffer from:

1. `xgboost` can't handle categorical features while `lightgbm` and `catboost` can.
2. `xgboost` can be more memory-hungry than `lightgbm` (although this can be mitigated).
3. `xgboost` can be slower than `lightgbm`.